# Logical question?

Tags: logical-deduction

This might be a bit broad, but still, I am wondering:

Imagine a game of logical deduction, involving a typical "cracking the code" scenario.

We have three numbers and a statement:

> `245` two numbers are correct but in the wrong place.

My question is; does the statement logically (and/or game wise) need to contain *all* the information there is to say about the number for the statement to be considered `true`?

For example, will the above statement exclude the following options:

> `245` two numbers are correct but in the wrong place and 1 is correct and in place.

or

> `245` three numbers are correct but in the wrong place.

My guess would be that *missing* information would not make the statement false. But still, it feels wrong to say `2 numbers are correct and not in the right place` if they all `3` were.

Comment: This is more a question about pedantry, in most cases. It's like when you ask someone, "How are you?" and if they say, "I'm alright," you say, "I didn't know you were called 'Alright'!"

Comment: "two numbers are correct but in the wrong place" = two correct numbers, both are in the wrong place
"two numbers are correct but in the wrong place and 1 is correct and in place" = all numbers are correct but only one of them is in the correct place
"three numbers are correct but in the wrong place" = all numbers are correct, all of them are in the wrong place.
The first answer should, by logic, exclude the other options, because it implies only two numbers are correct, but the other two answers state that all three numbers are correct.
Like Gareth said, its misleading if 2 was to mean 3.

Answer (score 1):

If the rules of the game say the statement has to say as much as possible, then it has to say as much as possible.

Otherwise, it's not *false* but it might be *misleading*. Whether that's good or bad will depend on context :-).

(Sometimes things like "this statement says as much as it could have done" are called *implicatures*; googling that will probably turn up a bunch of linguistic and philosophical stuff about the phenomenon. In ordinary conversation, a ton of information is conveyed by implicature rather than by what's actually said.)